# Get latest access log comparing records between two access log tables

Tags: mysql

Two tables that log access to projects.  I want to show the admin a list of projects/worksheets that he/she has not accessed since the user has last access that project/worksheet with an access_code of "e" (edited).

There may be a case where the admin has NEVER accessed that project/worksheet (i.e. no matching project/worksheet in admin table) (this is actually where I get stuck)

Obviously, what I was after is a single query that "does it all".. maybe dreaming..

admin_access
  project_id, wksheet_id, id, access_date, access_code
user_access
  project_id, wksheet_id, id, access_date, access_code

(where id is the user/admin id for that access event and access_date is a timestamp)

result table 
  project_id, wksheet_id

What I need is a list of records (project_id, wksheet_id) where the access_date in the table user_access is the greatest (i.e. admin has not access that project/worksheet since the user has last edited that worksheet. (note: the only other access_code is "v" for view))

It is not relevant that the admin had either viewed or edited that worksheet previously or which user had last access that record in the user_access table. (i.e. the id in the user_access table is not relevant)

I've gotten close but the killer seems to be where that admin does not have an access record in the admin_access table for that project. (max(date) returns NULL and then the comparison fails)

Looking for fresh angles on this..

Comment: Oops my tables where mangled..

Comment: admin_access: project_id, wksheet_id, id, access_date, access_code | user_access: project_id, wksheet_id, id, access_date, access_code

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something that works when the max(a.access_date) is NULL for the comparison

```
Select * from 

(SELECT u.project_id, u.wksheet_id, max(u.access_date) as user_date, max(a.access_date)   as admin_date FROM user_access u
  left outer join admin_access a on (a.project_id = u.project_id and a.wksheet_id = u.wksheet_id) 
where u.access_code = 'e'
group by u.project_id, u.wksheet_id) as maxtable

where maxtable.user_date > maxtable.admin_date or
  maxtable.admin_date is NULL
```

The key was to take the query that produces a good list of possible matching project/worksheets and use that in a select where the comparison accounts for the possible null from the max(a.access_date) from the missing matching admin_access record.

It would be interesting to hear other ways to do this...